# Access ObstacleLayer Costmap2D in localplanner

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, move-base, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way I can access Costmap2D of a layer in the local planner? I saw this question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/172670/accessing-data-of-different-layers-in-costmap2dros/), but I couldnt get it to work. The only way I can access the costmap is though layered_costmap_, but it is protected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200646/access-obstaclelayer-costmap2d-in-localplanner/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got confused with the CostmapLayer doxygen docs [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1CostmapLayer.html) which doesnt show inheritance from Costmap2D

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::Layer> >* plugins = costmap_ros_->getLayeredCostmap()->getPlugins();

for (std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::Layer> >::iterator pluginp = plugins->begin(); pluginp != plugins->end(); ++pluginp) {

boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::Layer> plugin = *pluginp;

if(plugin->getName().find(layer_search_string_)!=std::string::npos) {
    boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::CostmapLayer> costmap;
    costmap = boost::static_pointer_cast<costmap_2d::CostmapLayer>(plugin);
    unsigned char* grid = costmap->getCharMap();

    // do sth with it

}
```

}

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2